# Updating a column in MapInfo based on Symbology or colour

Tags: qgis, symbology, mapinfo, update

I am transferring a large dataset from MapInfo (V 12.0.2) to QGIS (V2.8.1) and I want to be able to  create a column in the MapInfo attribute table that differentiates features with different symbology (even if it differentiates with a number or letter), that way when I add the data to QGIS I can easily change the symbology to categorized style and re-format them the way they were in MapInfo. I styled my symbols using the style function, I did not use the thematic map tool.

I was able to do this with text data - meaning I could populate the column with the text that had been stored in the file, I am just wondering if this can be done with symbols or polygons?

I have tried the MapInfo-to-QGIS Style generator plugin and it would not work for me.

Comment: Edit the question with version information which will most likely be needed to get an answer from someone.

Comment: How did you symbolize different classes of features in MapInfo, as thematic map or using style attributes? With the latter you can use MapInfo as a geo-enabled graphics software. As far as I remember these attributes are written to mif/mid format. Unfortunatly I haven 't access to MapInfo the next days, so I cannot go into more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was able to solve this myself, unless anyone has a better way of doing it.

In MapInfo create a new column. Update this column using the value: **objectinfo(obj,2)**. Then convert the file to a shapefile. After loading into QGIS use categorized symbol of the new column you created. The symbols wont be the same as in Mapinfo, but at least you are able to differentiate your features.